# regular expression help needed

Tags: microsoft-word, notepad++, regex, text-editors, wordpad

I have a text of 8XX lines that look like this:

```
id="**02_item2_02" duration="29" style="**joe"
id="02_item3_01" duration="35.5" style="joseph"
```

The text between `id="` and `style="` is never the same. 
How can I replace anything to the right of the `id="`
and up through *and including* `style="`, so all my lines can look like:

```
id="joseph" bla!bla!bla! text from the script 
id="sara" bla!bla!bla! text from the script 
et cetera.
```

?

Comment: sorry for my English

Comment: I'm sorry to say, it's bad. (1) Does 8XX mean approximately 800? (2a) Do you have a text file or a Microsoft Word document? (2b) Do you need multiple answers (Word, Notepad++, WordPad) or just one? (2c) Are you willing to consider other tools? Are you able to access / willing to install Cygwin or another Unix-like environment? (3a) According to your example, you aren't replacing everything *between* `id="` and `style="`; you're replacing everything to the right of `id="` and up through *and including* `style="`. I edited your question to say so; fix it if I got it wrong. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3b) You aren't ***replacing*** text; you're ***deleting*** everything to the right of `id="` and up through *and including* `style="`. (3c) And then you're adding text at the end of the line. (4a) Where did `joe` go? (4b) Where did `sara` come from? … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex:

```
(id=").+style="(.+)
```

and replace with:

```
$1$2 blah blah blah! text from the script
```

Test: https://regex101.com/r/Z3zuIR/3